# How to generate site specific log file in multi site scenario?

Tags: multisite, logging, log4net

By default only one log file is created in multi-site scenario also.

We have come across requirement to generate log file as per site i.e. each site have its own log file. So it'll easy to debug and trace any issue.

**Example**
   www.site1.com  `log.site1.20190702.152425.txt`
   www.site2.com  `log.site2.20190702.152425.txt`

Please illuminate on custom implementation to achieve this.

Comment: Do you have a permanent list if sites? Do you need to create a special logger for each of them or do you need a logger will also be created when you create a new site?

Comment: I have permanent list of sites. I want to generate per site log file to easily investigate site specific issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, start by adding multiple `appender` to your app.config:

```
    <appender name="site1" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <file value="site1.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="site2" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="site2.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="ALL" />
    <appender-ref ref="site1" />
  </root>
  <logger additivity="false" name="site2">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
    <appender-ref ref="site2" />
  </logger>
```

then in code you can call them by:

```
ILog site1 = LogManager.GetLogger("site1");
ILog site2 = LogManager.GetLogger("site2");
```